# Summing/multiplying dictionaries with same keys within dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

Given a dataframe with multiple columns of dictionaries, how can I sum and/or multiply the keys within the dataframes together to get one column

```
                       A                        B
   {"ab":1, "b":2, "c":3}   {"ab":1, "b":3, "c":5}
```

So added together you get another column

```
                    C
{"ab":2, "b":5, "c":8}
```

Or multiplied together you get

```
                    C
{"ab":1, "b":6, "c":15}
```

I know if they were just columns of numbers I could use sum/etc., but whats the best way if they're columns of dictionaries? A lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Naive approach:***

Use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) which can handle *dict or list of dicts* as data input really well:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
processed_df = json_normalize(df.T.to_dict('list'), 0)
```

[image]

To find ***sum***:

```
processed_df.sum()    # Append .to_dict() if you want to render it as a dictionary
ab    2
b     5
c     8
dtype: int64
```

To find ***product***:

```
processed_df.prod()    # Append .to_dict() if you want to render it as a dictionary 
ab     1
b      6
c     15
dtype: int64
```

It would be an overkill if the dataframe has too many columns/rows which could although be overcome by melting it into a long form having a single column header. But again, reshaping it back to align the matching rows and calculating would be too much of a deal.

---

***More generalized approach:***

Sample `DF`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [{"ab":1, "b":2, "c":3}, {'b':4, 'c':5, 'ab':6}], 
                   'B': [{"ab":7, "b":8, "c":9}, {'b':10, 'c':11, 'ab':12}]})
df
```

[image]

Compute ***sum***:

```
df.stack().apply(pd.Series).sum(level=0)
```

[image]

Compute ***product***:

```
df.stack().apply(pd.Series).prod(level=0)
```

[image]

*Assigning* it back to a new column:

```
df['C'] = df.stack().apply(pd.Series).sum(level=0).to_dict('records')
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can first expand dicts to multi-column DFs `df.A.apply(pd.Series)`, make your arithmetic and finally convert result back to dict: `(result).to_dict('r')`:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
                              A                             B
0     {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'ab': 1}     {'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'ab': 1}
1  {'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'ab': 11}  {'b': 23, 'c': 25, 'ab': 21}

In [85]: df['C'] = (df.A.apply(pd.Series) + df.B.apply(pd.Series)).to_dict('r')

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
                              A                             B                             C
0     {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'ab': 1}     {'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'ab': 1}     {'b': 5, 'c': 8, 'ab': 2}
1  {'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'ab': 11}  {'b': 23, 'c': 25, 'ab': 21}  {'b': 35, 'c': 38, 'ab': 32}
```

Explanation:

```
In [91]: df.A.apply(pd.Series)
Out[91]:
   ab   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  11  12  13
```